# How to implement the following boolean function with a 8:1 mux?

Tags: multiplexer, boolean-algebra

The following boolean function is given
$$ f = (\neg a \land b \land \neg c) \lor (a \land b \land \neg c) \lor (a \land b \land c)$$

which should be implemented with a 8:1 mux.

> Write down the truth table.

I have the following truth table (abc - variables and f the function described above)

abcf 
0000 
0010 
0101 
0110 
1000 
1010 
1101 
1111

Is this correct?

Comment: Implementing a function using appropriately sized mux is the most straightforward thing that can be. You simply input `1`s on the lines corresponding to `1`s in the truth table, and use the selector inputs as an input.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I am not quite sure whether I understand it correctly, thats why I am asking.

Comment: Can you draw a truth table for MUX? While using labels `d0` through `d7` as the output values.

Comment: I know how a MUX is working but I am not quite sure how to implement the function above with a 8:1 MUX. I cant quite get my head around it. I know that a,b and c are there to control which of ``` dx ```  is chosen to be the output where x is an element of {0,1,..,7}.

Comment: I am trying to guide you to understanding. So can you draw such a table? If you can, then what should you do to make this table equivalent to your function? You will need to assign the `d`s the corresponding values.

Comment: If you know how mux is working and how a mux looks like, you would have solved this by now. Actually nothing is there to solve.

Comment: I think you are right, I dont understand it. I will look it up on the internet maybe I will understand it better. Sorry for asking

Comment: Looking up the answer won't help you understand it. What does a multiplexer do, exactly? If you understand that the answer will be pretty obvious.

Comment: @Finbarr I understand things much better when I see an example with solution such that I can go step by step through the example and then I adapt these steps but if that is really that obvious I should find it out myself but thank you all for trying to help me!

Comment: That's all fine until you're asked to do something new or come up with an idea.

Comment: @Finbarr I think I just understood the exercise wrongly. I did not understand that the boolean function is expected to be the output of the MUX. I thought I have to know the values of the input variables because the controls just swtich between them but in this case the output was already given by the function. Sorry for the misunderstanding! Now I see why you think that the solution is obvious

Comment: Good. Now you can put the answer yourself and finish this question off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, what’s shown in your table is correct. A mux (this is, a lookup table) is a valid way of making logic. It’s how FPGA logic works.

You can also express the function as a sum of products, as three 3-input AND gates followed by a 3-input OR. This is how it would work in programmable logic like a CPLD, or in an actual custom ASIC. This is more area-efficient than a full lookup table.

Comment: Hey, thank you.I think I overcomplicate things.